# advantages and disadvantages of ruby exception handling

Tags: ruby, exception

It's well known how easy it is to raise exceptions in Ruby and it's suggested to inherit your own exceptions from `StandardError` or `RuntimeError`. And I'd like to systematize all best practices and suggestions into concise list of advantages and disadvantages of Ruby exception handling. Question:

> *what are advantages and disadvantages of ruby exception handling?*

Comment: This question makes no sense. Even if you can dream up some disadvantages of exception handling, the alternative is for your application to exit on a failure, potentially irking clients or users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could have a long discussion on this, or you could get the "Exceptional Ruby" eBook by Avdi Grim, which is a substantial discussion on the topic by a well-known Rubyist and quite a steal at USD15.

http://exceptionalruby.com/

Comment: If I would read a hole book for each question it would take 100 mln years.

Comment: Did you even check that the book is a mere 100 pages or so? Programming best practices aren't just some bullet points you can follow...

Comment: I didn't. Thanks for advice. Michael, I wrote this question because I need a quick answer. If I have more time and be interested I will read this book no doubt. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: take a little time to educate yourself and you will not be constantly blocked needing quick answers, because you will already know the answers, or where to look to find them again.  It's an investment well worth the time if you aim to be good at your craft.